# .NET MVC4 UrlHelper Action returns all lowercase route values

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Given the following UrlHelper extension method:

```
public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url, string action, string controller, object routeValues)
{
    Uri requestUrl = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

    string absoluteAction = 
            string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
            requestUrl.Scheme,
            requestUrl.Authority,
            url.Action(action, controller, routeValues));

    return absoluteAction;
}
```

I have a property on my object (routeValues) that is an api key. When I get the value back from AbsoluteAction I would expect http://www.mysite.com/controller/action?apikey=PassWord1234 but instead I get http://www.mysite.com?/controller/action/apikey=password1234. It seems to be the .NET UrlHelper Action method that is causing the problem, but I see no way of specifying "keep my original casing".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `Url.Action` helper doesn't automatically lowercase the values.

Assuming default routing setup, the following call:

```
string url = Url.Action("foo", "bar", new { apikey = "PassWord1234" });
```

generates:

```
/bar/foo?apikey=PassWord1234
```

Maybe you are using some custom routes that might be causing this behavior but out of the box ASP.NET MVC would absolutely not do this.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. That would also explain why I can't find anything similar on Google! I'll look into our custom routes and see what I find there. Cheers!

Comment: Yep. That was exactly it. Had to add a specific route mapping for this particular route as we default everything else to lowercase. Thanks Darin!